# Post a message to ActiveMQ using CURL

Tags: curl, post, activemq-classic

I want to post a message to ActiveMQ broker using Curl. Actually I created a broker in java by BrokerFactory:

```
public BrokerService createBrokerSendReceiveMessage(String brokerSchemeUrl, String brokerName)
  throws Exception {
return BrokerFactory.createBroker(brokerSchemeUrl + brokerName);
```

}

The broker works very well but when I want to send a message with Curl I get this error:

> Transport:243 - Transport Connection to: tcp://127.0.0.1:62208 failed: java.io.IOException: Unknown data type: 97

I use Mac and in the terminal, I write the following command:

```
curl -XPOST -u admin:admin  -d 'body="Hello World"' "http://localhost:61616/demo/message/study?type=queue"
```

The broker runs locally on port 61616 and the queue name is "study".
What is the problem? Could you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveMQ's REST interface is a web application which runs in an embedded Jetty instance. It doesn't appear that you've configured this.

By default the broker will listen for *OpenWire* connections on port `61616`. Since `curl` uses HTTP the broker chokes on the request.